# How can I aggregate on elasticsearch only values that occur in both indices?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

How can I make a search in elasticsearch for two indices that aggregates the values that occur in both indices?

For instance:

```
GET indexA,indexB/_search 
{
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myField"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way I get all the values that myField has in both indices (indexA and indexB) but how can I change this so that it only shows the values that appear both in indexA and indexB?

To clarify, if myField has values value1, value2 and value3 in indexA
but it only has value1 and value2 in indexB, my search would only show value1 and value2.

Comment: Be careful, by default aggregation only get 10 results, you need to change the size to get all different MyField.

Comment: Are those values unique for one type??

Comment: Anyway, i think you can't do that directly with ES

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (and you need Elasticsearch 2.x):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myField"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_indices": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "_index"
          }
        },
        "values_bucket_filter_by_index_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "count_indices"
            },
            "script": "count >= 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With `"terms": {"field": "myField"}` you get the unique `myField` values. Then, as a sub-aggregation, with `"cardinality": {"field": "_index"}` you count the number of indices that have that value and with the final aggregation - `values_bucket_filter_by_index_count` - you keep those buckets that have at least two indices containing them.

In the end the aggregations result look like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "myField": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "value1",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "count_indices": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "value2",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "count_indices": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

As I mentioned you need Elasticsearch 2.x for `bucket_selector` aggregation.

Comment: Any idea if I could use this search in kibana?

Comment: I don't think bucket_selector is available in Kibana